# How to pass the data in nested Dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog

I have a dialog fragment which has six buttons.when a user clicks on the button, a color picker is open.The color data is then pass to the first dialog fragment and individual color is set on the button.
[Dialog Fragment 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx4pIec6rk6BZGdySEI2ejlRTmVzVmlfQ0s1ZzVyWVJBMlFZ) .
The problem is when i declare the interface method,i am able to get the data in fragment or activity but not able to get the data to the dialog fragment 1.
How to pass the data from the dialog fragment 2 to dialog fragment 1 ?

I want to pass the touchedRGB color to first dialog fragment.

Is it possible to send data using getter and setter in the color model,if yes how to do it?

```
    builder.setView(layout)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            ColorDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
                            mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(ColorDialog.this);//calling the listener 

                        }
                    })
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            ColorModel colormodel = new ColorModel();
                            colormodel.setColorData(ColorData);
                            mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(ColorDialog.this);
                            mListener.receiveColorData(touchedRGB); //calling the listener 
                        }
                    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Dialog Fragment 1

```
public class addMain extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener,ColorDialog.ColorDialogListener {

    Button  color1,color2,color3,color4,color5,color6,canceladd,okadd;
    SeekBar seek = null;
    public int touchedRGB = 000000;
    Integer[] coloranimchange={0,0,0,0,0,0},customvisibility={0,0,0,0,0,0};
    Button scenes;
    EditText custtomname;
    String theme;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.ColoePickerDialogStyle);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogadd, null);


        color1 = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.addcolor1);
        color2 = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.addcolor2);
        color3 = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.addcolor3);
        color4 = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.addcolor4);
        color5 = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.addcolor5);
        color6 = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.addcolor6);
        custtomname = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.themename);

        color1.setOnClickListener(this);
        color2.setOnClickListener(this);
        color3.setOnClickListener(this);
        color4.setOnClickListener(this);
        color5.setOnClickListener(this);
        color6.setOnClickListener(this);

        builder.setView(layout)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                addMain.this.getDialog().cancel();

                            }
                        })
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            }
                        });
        return builder.create();

    }


    public static String[] getArray(String input) {
        return input.split("\\|\\$\\|SEPARATOR\\|\\$\\|");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ColorDialog dialogFragment = new ColorDialog();
        dialogFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "ColorSelect");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {

    }

    @Override
    public void receiveColorData(int ColorData) {
        String col = String.valueOf(ColorData);
        Log.v("col",col);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Share the whole nested class please

Comment: Can you post the picture of your UI how it looks

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx4pIec6rk6BZGdySEI2ejlRTmVzVmlfQ0s1ZzVyWVJBMlFZ/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were just implement the ColorDialog.ColorDialogListener, but you forgot to set callback to ColorDialog.

**Dialog Fragment 1**

```
ColorDialog dialogFragment = new ColorDialog();
dialogFragment.setCallBack(this);
dialogFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "ColorSelect");
```

**ColorDialog**

```
public ColorDialog extends DialogFragment {
   private ColorDialogListener mCallback;

   public void setCallBack(ColorDialogListener listener) {
       this.mCallback = listener;
   }

   public interface ColorDialogListener {
          public void onColorSelect(ColorModel model);
   }

  /** Now you call back is ready to send data**/
  mCallback.onColorSelect(colorModel )
}
```

Comment: that's great. Welcome.